# "cannot set OID on symbolic reference" when trying to fast-forward with libgit2

Tags: c++, c, libgit2

**Note:** I tagged *C* and *C++* since *libgit2* is a *C* library and I'm writing a *C++* wrapper for common git commands. We'll see here both *C* and *C++* code and as far as I am concerned it does not matter if I get a *C* or *C++* oriented solution (I'll adapt it myself if needed).

---

I'm trying to perform a fast-forward update of a repository in a `gitPull()` function when the branch is fast-forwardable (using *libgit2*). I want to perform a merge only when necessary.

My strategy looks as follows (I removed the error-checking, ... in order to target only the essentials and to make the code as simple as possible):

```
// INFO: I assume here I already have an open repository in a "repo" variable.

// Do the fetch --> works fine
// ...

// Compare HEAD and FETCH_HEAD
git_oid head_id;
git_reference_name_to_id(&head_id, repo, "HEAD");
git_oid fetch_head_id;
git_reference_name_to_id(&fetch_head_id, repo, "FETCH_HEAD");

if(!git_oid_equal(&fetch_head_id, &head_id)) // A pull is needed
{
    // Check if we can fast-forward or need a merge
    git_annotated_commit * fetch_head_annotated_commit = nullptr;
    git_annotated_commit_lookup(&fetch_head_annotated_commit, repo, &fetch_head_id);

    git_merge_analysis_t an_out;
    git_merge_preference_t pref_out;
    git_merge_analysis(&an_out, &pref_out, repo, const_cast<const git_annotated_commit **>(&fetch_head_annotated_commit),1);

    if(an_out & GIT_MERGE_ANALYSIS_FASTFORWARD) // A fast-forward is possible
    {
        git_reference * head_ref = nullptr;
        git_reference_lookup(&head_ref, repo, "HEAD");

        git_reference * new_head_ref = nullptr;
        git_reference_set_target(&new_head_ref, head_ref, &fetch_head_id, "");

        git_checkout_head(repo, nullptr);

        git_reference_free(new_head_ref);
        git_reference_free(head_ref);
    }
    else // A merge is needed
    {
        // Do the merge and create the related commit
        // ...
    }
    git_annotated_commit_free(fetch_head_annotated_commit);
}
```

What is strange is that the condition `if(an_out & GIT_MERGE_ANALYSIS_FASTFORWARD)` is `true` but when I run the function `git_reference_set_target(&new_head_ref, head_ref, &fetch_head_id, "");`, I get the following error:

> "cannot set OID on symbolic reference"

---

I have made a research and I found in the [source code of *libgit2* in *refs.c*](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/src/refs.c) what you can see below:

> ```
> static int ensure_is_an_updatable_direct_reference(git_reference *ref)
> {
>     if (ref->type == GIT_REFERENCE_DIRECT)
>         return 0;
>
>     git_error_set(GIT_ERROR_REFERENCE, "cannot set OID on symbolic reference");
>     return -1;
> }
>
> int git_reference_set_target(
>     git_reference **out,
>     git_reference *ref,
>     const git_oid *id,
>     const char *log_message)
> {
>     int error;
>     git_repository *repo;
>
>     assert(out && ref && id);
>
>     repo = ref->db->repo;
>
>     if ((error = ensure_is_an_updatable_direct_reference(ref)) < 0)
>         return error;
>
>     return git_reference_create_matching(out, repo, ref->name, id, 1, &ref->target.oid, log_message);
> }
> ```

By reading this code, we can see that the issue is that the `ref` parameter which is the *"HEAD"* reference in my case, is not an "updatable direct reference".
In other words, there is no direct path found from *"HEAD"* to *"FETCH_HEAD"* (as I passed the `fetch_head_id`).

What I don't understand is that, if I am correct, the way to check if a branch can be fast-forwarded is to verify if it exists a direct path between *"HEAD"* and *"FETCH_HEAD"*.

So it seems contradictory in my mind to enter the condition and hear it said that it is not an "updatable direct reference".

---

My question is: **What did I miss ? What did I misunderstand ?** (quite wide question I know, this is why I provided as many details as possible).

I will be very grateful for any tips that will help me to get rid of my issue and make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This morning I just realized i'm quite stupid :)

*"HEAD"* is a symbolic reference to *"refs/heads/master"* in my case. So what the error notifies is that I need to pass the direct reference, not an alias.